# Google is mixing GitHub and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, google

I don’t know if anybody cares, but Google is apparently mixing up GitHub and Stack Overflow:

[image: 'Stack Overflow' description showing the logo of GitHub]

You can find this at the bottom of [every Google Glass documentation page](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/glass-at-work).

I propose that a Stack Exchange representative contacts them and request to change that GitHub logo into a Stack Overflow logo, at least they are violating Stack Exchange’s trademark.

Comment: Looks like a mistake, someone should probably let them know

Comment: @Pekka웃 Definitely, they know the correct logo, for instance: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: Google glass is doing this?  Time to burninate [tag:google-gdk] to show them who we are ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @BhargavRao or rename the tag to `microsoft-gdk`

Comment: For those voting to close: The question is within the scope defined in the help center: "Meta is for... Stack Overflow users to communicate with Stack Exchange the company".

Comment: I would call this a bug and inform them through their proper channels.  Google knows well what Stack Overflow is, considering [a few](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/info) [of their](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) [sponsored tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-glass/info), so I doubt that this is anything that the community team really needs to get involved in.

Comment: The funny thing is that there img src says clearly that it is github logo :) `<img class="devsite-footer-promo-icon" src="/site-assets/logo-github.svg">` So the developer did not drink enough coffee that night.

Comment: @BhargavRao Yeah, looks like they copy&pasted the text from one of their other documentations but forgot to change the logo. Here is another documentation with text and logo matching: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: Oh no! Copy-Paste takes the blame again :(

Comment: OK, but why are you telling us?  Tell Google, they're the ones who can fix it.

Comment: @davidism I’m not the one being paid by Stack Exchange to protect their trademark. I just wanted to inform them and if anyone cares (s)he can inform Google.

Comment: Also reported [on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259483/github-logo-for-stack-overflow-on-google-developers-page).

Comment: This is simple human mistake not more than that anyone can do these type of mistakes. Someone can intimate them they will fix it.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot remember how many times I contacted companies to fix things without mentioning pubilcally. Sometimes I get something in exchange (like recently some Wordpress Premium themes after giving them advice on how to fix things). OTOH you are right in that you're not a representative.

Comment: @phresnel And it seems like a [user already had contacted Google before without success](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259483/github-logo-for-stack-overflow-on-google-developers-page).

Comment: @idmean: Ah oh.

Comment: You could also raise the same issue with github.

Comment: If you seriously think you can "contact Google and get it fixed", clearly you have never tried to reach a human at Google.

Comment: I like the cat as SO logo ;)

Comment: @tripleee This is *exactly* why I brought this up here and why I'm requesting that Stack Exchange should do this. (Hopefully they can reach somebody.)

Comment: Where's @shanselman when you need him?

Comment: [Action is now being taken by a Stack Exchange employee](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259483/github-logo-for-stack-overflow-on-google-developers-page#comment860781_259554) as was requested three months ago, we'll see where that leads. Also, to anyone who is now trying to close this question as off-topic for Meta after it has already been reopened, **don't**. This is perfectly on-topic for Meta.

Comment: GitOverflow ! !

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Director of Ad Sales here. I've reached out to my contacts on the advertising side to see if I can get this changed. I'll keep everyone posted.

Update: This has been corrected!

[image]

Comment: Didn't SE give you a diamond next to your name?

Comment: Nope - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161197/keep-employee-on-the-profile-of-se-employees-on-meta

Comment: It's kind of a pity that they don't give you anything official like a diamond. I admit that I was a little suspicious that you were who you said you were.

Comment: Score for the ad sales team!

Comment: Guess only brute force helps sometimes... ;)

Comment: @Thunderforge http://stackexchange.com/about/team - Danny is listed there, and it links to this user profile - ultimate proof he's indeed who he says he is. (Unless of course he's a clever hacker who forged the team page ;))

Comment: Maybe you'd get a diamond if you spot this stuff yourself :)

Comment: And the logo's wrong again... Because SE decided to get a new SO logo. :P

Comment: @Danny Don't want to raise another question. They are still using the old SO symbol. Can you do something bout that too?

Comment: @BhargavRao I'll reach out tomorrow when I'm in the office. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyMiller Sorry to ping but it's still the old one. While less of an issue, it's bugging me :/

Comment: @Tim Don't be sorry - thanks for letting me know. The logo is now corrected!

Comment: @DannyMiller  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360116/google-strikes-again-now-mixing-google-and-stack-overflow?cb=1 Google strikes again! Now mixing Google+ and Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Lets enhance your calm.

I just filled in the form at http://www.google.com/glass/help/contact-us.html and expect this to be fixed soon..

**Update: (2 days later)**
I got a (2nd) response now resolving the issue, so *somebody* read it. I see its now resolved although more likely due to Danny.
But i'd have to agree that the email content lacks any human touch, which goes on to say "enjoy your Glass" which was obviously irrelevant.

Comment: I doubt something will happen soon but let’s see...

Comment: Its not really that important, but since some here make contacting a Google human sound impossible: its as simple as calling 1-844-GLASS-84 between 5am-9pm PST.  Source: that website.

Comment: Possibly you will be connected to somebody trying to sell Google Glass, but the person will likely not have the responsibility to modify the documentation. But let us wait and see if something happens.

Comment: This was [done *three months ago*](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/iz9Bme2x_C4;context-place=forum/sites) with absolutely zero resulting action. [Action *is* now being taken by a Stack Exchange employee](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259483/github-logo-for-stack-overflow-on-google-developers-page#comment860781_259554) as was [requested *three months ago*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259483/288751).

Comment: @idmean But did it enhance your calm?

Answer (score -12):

Glass is no longer part of Google.  As of Jan 2015 it's under Nest.

http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/15/7552349/google-glass-tony-fadell-explorer-shut-down

Comment: Did you even read the question...?

Comment: It's still under Google...since Nest is owned by Google...though that has nothing to do with the question...