# Google strikes again! Now mixing Google+ and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, google, outsourcing

It seems to me that Google likes mixing up logos. Two years ago [mixing GitHub and Stack Overflow logos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303804/3599179) and now mixing Google Developers Google+ and Stack Overflow logos.

Go visit [Google Developers Newsletter](https://developers.google.com/newsletter/) and scroll down to the bottom of the page and you'll find this:

[image]

Comment: Google is the next Skynet

Comment: Sometimes it feels like Google is the current Skynet ...

Comment: Let's rename [tag:google-plus] to [tag:facebook-like] to show them who we are!!! ಠ_ಠ ..... *(yup, I'm stealing BhargavRao and  Pekka 웃)*

Comment: On Monday I'll try to find out who's responsible for the newsletter internally, and see if we can avoid it happening again. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for taking care of this. Big respect for you guys at Google. Cheers!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: [I think we all know the answer to that.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foregone%20conclusion)

Comment: If we consider that "j" and "y" are written almost the same, Skynet would be an anagram from Jon Skeet !!!! So, your theory is confirmed @Teemu , o_O  !! (Only, I am not sure what the remaining letters from Jon Skeet would signify in this context : "T", "O", "E")

Comment: @Cedric: Organic Test Environment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is now fixed - thanks for pointing it out :)

(I can't actually take the credit - I wasn't the first to note it internally.)